# UnsupportedOperationException: No format processor for org.jboss...MavenResolvedArtifact was found

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, dependency-resolver

I'm creating an application to automatically generate resources for a launcher, this requires automatically resolving maven dependencies, but I'm getting an UnsupportedOperationException while running JBoss Shrinkwrap Resolver

I'm running this inside a docker container, to avoid the local repository caching, it works outside of the container on the host, but I'm unsure what is missing inside the container.

My resolver config is a simple example, converting to a `MavenResolvedArtifact`

```java
MavenResolvedArtifact[] artifacts = Maven.configureResolver()
            .withMavenCentralRepo(true)
            .withRemoteRepo("internal-nexus", MAVEN_URL, "default")
            .resolve("com.company:application:" + PROJECT_VERSION)
            .withTransitivity()
            .asResolvedArtifact();
```

My Dockerfile is also relatively simple, using openjdk9, including the bootstrapper program, a shell script and some environment variables.

```
FROM openjdk:9

COPY bootstrapper-shaded.jar /bootstrapper.jar
COPY docker-run.sh /run.sh

ENV CLONE_URL https://github.com/company/repository.git
ENV NEXUS_BASE https://nexus.company.com/
ENV NEXUS_REPO repository

RUN chmod +x /run.sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git software-properties-common maven

ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

And the run.sh script copies some files (removed for brevity), runs the build, then the bootstrapper

```sh
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf /boostrap/*
cd /bootstrap/
git clone $CLONE_URL work
cd work
chmod +x ./gradlew
./gradlew clean build
NEXUS_URL=`printf $NEXUS_BASE; printf "/repository/"; printf $NEXUS_REPO` ./gradlew upload
java -jar /bootstrapper.jar 0
```

I expect the output to be the same as on the host machine, an array of `MavenResolvedArtifact`s, however the following exception is thrown on the final line of the code snippet, `.asResolvedArtifact()`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No format processor for org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.MavenResolvedArtifact was found. Supported processors are: class org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.archive.ArchiveFormatProcessor
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.spi.format.FormatProcessors.find(FormatProcessors.java:53)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenFormatStageImpl.as(MavenFormatStageImpl.java:84)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenFormatStageImpl.asResolvedArtifact(MavenFormatStageImpl.java:71)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenFormatStageImpl.asResolvedArtifact(MavenFormatStageImpl.java:40)
    at com.company.ResolveTask.run(ResolveTask.java:39)
    at com.company.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:102)
```

Apologies for any typos in the stacktrace, VM wouldn't let me copy-paste out of it so I had to type it out myself.

Update: Haven't found anything else on google yet, have tried clean builds to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the type of artifacts to

> org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.archive.ArchiveFormatProcessor

or at least cast it to that when you declare.